# How to split & merge mpeg video files

Tags: c#

I am given with a project where advertisements are added in between serials. So for that we need to first split the video file into pieces and merge it with those advertisements. Can anyone help me out in this.

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg can do that, but I assume you want a c# library? If you do please edit your question.

And beware ffmpeg is GPL. On the project I worked on we installed ffmpeg separatly and called it from our program in an external process.

And we had to build ffmpeg ourselves, we used mingw

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ffmpeg

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/mingw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/mingw])

[edit] Ansver to comment:
 Sorry I don't have anything personally. But you tagged the question c# so if that was the only type you wanted it would be best to say so in the question.

I did however have another thought, have you looked into the [Windows Media SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmedia/default.aspx)?

Comment: Hi
 Nifle. Its not specific to any language. If you have the code for this in any other language, that is also appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MEncoder, also GPL.

[MEncoder (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MEncoder)

Answer (score -4):

Use any professional video editing software like Adobe Premier (http://www.adobe.com/products/premiere/).